# How do clichés evolve and change?

Tags: historical-change, cliche

I'm unsure if this isn't better suited for Literature SE, so bear with me, I'll take it over there if voted to close.

A friend shared an image with me where someone was complaining that *Pride and Prejudice* is heavily clichéd. This has spiraled into a discussion of how yes, to a modern reader I'm sure many classics are rife with clichés, but that's only because they have influenced our modern world so that their writings are now considered to have clichés. Of course, to a writer's contemporaries, the clichés we think of now weren't necessarily cliché back then. After all, the very first time the prince who saved the princess from the tower was told it was a wholly original story. Nowadays it's one of our most recognisable fairytale tropes.

We're now wondering about the mechanics of clichés and literary tropes and how they fall into and out of fashion, and pondering what a reader two hundred years ago might have read and thought "ugh, that's *sooo* cliché", which nowadays we wouldn't pick up on as it is no longer considered a cliché.

**Is there much study into the mechanics that create and destroy clichés? Where can I look to find clichés that are no longer considered cliché?**

Comment: Can you give an example of a cliche that has been rehabilitated?

Comment: You've got it backwards. A cliche is an overused phrase, and overuse refers to current usage habits. So in 2021, saying Jane Austen is full of cliches means that her phrases have become (or remained) popular for 200 years. This is something to be proud of, not ashamed of. Look at Shakespeare -- nothing but cliches from start to finish, except for the parts we don't understand.